# jQuery - stop url anchors from changing page position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a document with a bunch of sections that have information that I need to gather based on the URL anchor.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

**URL**

`http://mywebsite.com/page.php#section-2`

**html**

```
<div id='information'>Data should be here!</div>

<div id='section-1'>This is data from section 1!</div>

<div id='section-2'>This is data from section 2!</div>

<div id='section-3'>This is data from section 3!</div>

<div id='section-4'>This is data from section 4!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height: 500px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(!hash == ""){
    var data = $(hash).text();
    $("#information").text(data);
}
```

But when I load the URL, The jQuery works fine, But the page jumps down to `#section-2`.
How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to fix it!
For some reason, The timing was messing it up and causing the `$('body').scrollTop(0);` not to work.

**I was able to fix it by adding a 10 ms delay before scrolling to the top of the page.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(hash){
    setTimeout( function(){ 
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
    }, 10 );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You condition is incorrect. It should be `!=` instead.

```
if(hash != ""){
    var data = $(hash).text();
    $("#information").text(data);
}
```

And to prevent from jumping you can try using `scrollTop()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash){
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
  }
});
```

```css
div{
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='information'>Data should be here!</div>

<div id='section-1'>This is data from section 1!</div>

<div id='section-2'>This is data from section 2!</div>

<div id='section-3'>This is data from section 3!</div>

<div id='section-4'>This is data from section 4!</div>
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. I don't need help with gathering the data, I need it to stop the page jumping to the anchor.

Comment: Saw the Edit, Tried that too. It still jumps to the anchor.

Comment: I've just tried that, it still doesn't jump to the top. I did open the chrome developer console ran `$('body').scrollTop(0);` though that and it jumped properly. The full code that I'm using is too "over the place" to have a full example, But I've edited in the source page to my question.

Answer (score 0):

the browser will jump if there is a visible div with id = hash in the page. One way to prevent this is to set your divs display = none in the css so they are not visible during page load and then change them to visible immediately after

```
$(function() {
  $('div').show();
});
```

Or perhaps you might only want to show one section at a time..

```
$(function() {
  $('#section-2').show();
});
```

another way might be to leave the divs visible but immediately scroll back to top of page

```
$(function() {
  self.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the div to be shown. I've tried the `self.scrollTo(0, 0);` but like the other answers, It doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure what's stopping it :/

Comment: I already posted the answer, a simple 10ms delay before scrolling. - See answer

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a way to fix it!
For some reason, The timing was messing it up and causing the `$('body').scrollTop(0);` not to work.

**I was able to fix it by adding a 10 ms delay before scrolling to the top of the page.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(hash){
    setTimeout( function(){ 
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
    }, 10 );
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, But it doesn't seem to work. The page still jumps to the anchor.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: I will not be able to fiddle with the code. You need to add a demo.